# How to query PostgreSQL by filtering a timestamp column with time zone for a given weekday and time range

Tags: postgresql, datetime

Let's say I have a table which has a column of type timestamp with time zone. Let's call it **record_timestamptz**. I am trying to fetch only the records which have **record_timestamptz** in a given time slice of a specific day of the week (or between two consecutive days of the week). Let's suppose I am trying to fetch all the records between Wednesdays 23:00 and Thursdays 03:00 (UTC time).

The query that I came up with does not work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE (
    EXTRACT (DOW FROM record_timestamptz::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') =
    EXTRACT (DOW FROM TIMESTAMP '2016-02-03 23:00:00+00') 
    AND
    record_timestamptz::time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' >= '23:00:00'::time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') 
    OR 
    (EXTRACT (DOW FROM record_timestamptz::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') =
    EXTRACT (DOW FROM TIMESTAMP '2016-02-04 03:00:00+00') 
    AND 
    record_timestamptz::time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' <= '03:00:00'::time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
) 
ORDER BY record_timestamptz DESC
```

The problem is that the "at time zone 'UTC'" on either side does not do anything. The output of the query is giving me records between "23:00:00-2" and "03:00:00-2" instead of "21:00:00+00" and "01:00:00+00", given that all the records in the database have a time zone offset of -2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *, record_timestamptz at time zone 'utc' 
from
    t
    right outer join
    (
        select tstzrange(d, d + interval '6 hours') as r
        from generate_series (
            '2016-01-27 21:00:00+00'::timestamptz, '2016-03-31', '7 day'
        ) gs (d)
    ) gs on record_timestamptz <@ gs.r
order by gs.r desc
```

Comment: I guess I was not very clear about the fact that I am also interested in the records from '2016-01-27 21:00:00+00' till '2016-01-28 01:00:00+00';  '2016-01-20 21:00:00+00' till '2016-01-21 01:00:00+00'; and so on

Comment: I have been trying to use your query but I am getting a "syntax error at or near where". I understood what you're doing but couldn't fix the problem. It seems that the alias "gs" for the tstzrange is not being accepted.